# How to get filesource from Intervention Image?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Intervention image package to resize and crop upload images.

```
$img = Image::make($source)
        ->resize($resize['width'], $resize['height'], function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        })
        ->encode()->stream();
```

But I need to store into S3 like this:

```
$s3Client->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $s3_bucket,
        'Key'    => $Key,
        'Body'   => fopen($img, 'r+')
    ]);
```

fopen(): Argument #1 ($filename) must not contain any null bytes

Comment: You can use the base64 method, which will encode the image as a base64 string that you can pass to the Body option of the putObject

Comment: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...

Comment: I see... try  saving the image to a temporary file and pass the file path to the fopen function, it should work I think